# How To get Payment By Paid Apps uploaded in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I am an android programmer . Recently I have developed an android software and now want to uploaded this apps in Google Play Store . I want to up this app as paid apps . I have come to know that I have to open an account in Google Play Store by $30 .

But I have some confusion regarding this whole matter . Can u plz help me by answering the following question .
        1. WHEN people buy the app from google play store how will I get paid for the app
        2. Can I first upload the app as free app and then turn this app as paid app ?

Comment: Maybe you could google a little before asking questions here, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/173779?hl=en&ref_topic=15867

Comment: just go through this link.. its useful for you..http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.WHEN people buy the app from google play store how will I get paid for the app

**Ans** you have to link your merchant account with your developer console you can do this by

**1)** First, log into your Google Play Developer Console.

**2)** Click on the Financial reports tab in the left navigation bar.

**3)** From there, select Set up a merchant account now.

**4)** then follow the steps and then go to Account and click on add account then fill out the form and then follow what they say.

2.Can I first upload the app as free app and then turn this app as paid app

**Ans** No You can't it is asked before hands that your app is paid or free.

Answer (score 4):

1. You will get paid via your bank account. You need to register a bank account with Google Play Mechanism. After that, you will receive a confirmation amount via email. Enter this amount to verify your Google account, then you can receive money via this bank account. You will receive it once a month. Also, you can check the payment history as well.
2. You can't. You need to identify it clearly before uploading it as you can't change in the future.